# How to put nth-child inside a class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm using nth-child in a table to define the widths of headers and colums as so

```
th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) { width: 72px !important; }
th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2) { width: 170px !important; }
th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) { width: 95px !important; }
th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) { width: 65px !important;}
th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5) { width: 90px  !important; }
th:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(6) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(7) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(8), td:nth-child(8) { width: 90px  !important; }
th:nth-child(9), td:nth-child(9) { width: 90px  !important; }
th:nth-child(10), td:nth-child(10) { width: 90px  !important;}
```

However I have multiple tables in my page and I only want to apply it to one table. so I would like to put them inside a class like so

```
.myFixedHeaders{
th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) { width: 72px !important;}
th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2) { width: 170px !important;}
th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) { width: 95px !important;}
th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) { width: 65px !important;}
th:nth-child(5), td:nth-child(5) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(6) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(7) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(8), td:nth-child(8) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(9), td:nth-child(9) { width: 90px  !important;}
th:nth-child(10), td:nth-child(10) { width: 90px  !important;}
}
```

But it doesn't work.  How can I apply it to one table and not all three?

Comment: You need to add `.myFixedHeaders` *before every* selector range, e.g: `.myFixedHeaders th:nth-child(1), .myFixedHeaders td:nth-child(1) {...}` It may easier for you to maintain and manage moving forward if you just use classes instead, most of those cells are the same width, so define a general `width` property value to cover most of the cells, then declare unique styles to the first three `nth` elements with more specific selectors, e.g: `.myFixedHeaders th:nth-child(1)`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError  thank you sir ! That works :)